# Hive SQL Distinct Column Syntax Error when calling multiple columns

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, count, distinct

After using a WITH clause and series of inner joins, I attempted to call back three columns: Employees, SalesID and a COUNT(DISTINCT) and encountered a Syntax Error.

This is for a hadoop environment with hive sql. With SELECT Employees, SalesID, Workload, all appropriate data recalls; however, a syntax issue arises when performing the COUNT(DISTINCT).

Successful Results:

```
SELECT SalesID
, COUNT(DISTINCT workload) AS Cases

GROUP BY SalesID
```

Also Successful Results:

```
SELECT EmployeeName
    , SalesID
    , Workload AS Cases

ORDER BY SalesID
```

Syntax Error:

```
SELECT  EmployeeName
    , SalesID
    , COUNT(DISTINCT workload) Cases

GROUP BY SalesID
```

I expect the output to reflect:

```
EmployeeName   | SalesID | Cases
First Last1    | 12345   |   4
First Last2    | 23455   |   2
First Last3    | 45633   |   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, none of your queries have a `FROM` clause, so all should generate syntax errors.

More importantly, the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists should match -- all unaggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  EmployeeName, SalesID, COUNT(DISTINCT workload) as Cases
FROM t
GROUP BY EmployeeName SalesID
```